# Google Crawler or Scraper with all search parameters

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, google-search

I have a list of 1 million website url and I have a list of key words. I want to use Google to search for this keywords on those websites one by one; if I find some thing that's mean it's a valid URL for me.

I was Googling to find some tool to do it, I found two.

https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper after installing everything I find that this scraper doesn't support "as_sitesearch" as a search parameter so I can not search by website.

Same thing for the 2nd one: http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm

Is there any good tool to do that?

Comment: Can you explain more what `as_sitesearch` does? If you want to run a Google query for a specific domain, you can usually just do something like this: `domain:stackoverflow.com php`. I think the `site:` keyword has a special meaning too.

Comment: @halfer on google advanced search page you can add a website or a domain then you will find the link as a get paramated named &as_sitesearch=

Comment: Sounds like my alternative above will work, then. Just add one of those clauses to your search string.

Comment: no google search bar it work but on GoogleScraper no because the scraper read only keyword

Comment: Can you modify one of these scrapers so the site filter is sent in the search along with the keyword? There should be a `cURL` call, or something like that.

Comment: @halfer I really wanted to use the python Google Scraper because it open a virtual browser, but I cannot modify on it and I'm not very comfortable with python so now I'm building my own using the 2nd Java library that I just mention

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am the programmer of [GoogleScraper](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper). You can use the 'as_sitesearch' parameter when you use keyword files for your 1 million keywords.

Just use GoogleScraper something like this:

`GoogleScraper --mode selenium --keyword-file you-keyword.txt --proxy-file your-proxies`

where the file **you-keyword.txt** looks like:

`site:yourdomain.com some sneaky words
site:yourdomain2.com some other words
...`

To view all help:

`GoogleScraper --help`

Cheers